# Checking to see if a generic class is inherited from an interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I've got a class that inherits from an interface. That interface defines an event that I'd like to subscribe to in the calling code. I've tried a couple of things, but they all resolve to false (where I know it's true). How can I check to see if a class implements a specific interface.

Here's what I've tried (note, the object in question is a usercontrol that implements MyInterface, stored in an array of controls, only some of which implement MyInterface - it is not null):

```
if (this.controls[index].GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(MyInterface)))
    ((MyInterface)this.controls[index]).Event += this.Handler;
```

---

```
if (this.controls[index].GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyInterface)))
    ((MyInterface)this.controls[index]).Event += this.Handler;
```

---

```
if (this.controls[index].GetType() == typeof(MyInterface))
    ((MyInterface)this.controls[index]).Event += this.Handler;
```

All to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (typeof(MyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(this.controls[index].GetType()))
    ((MyInterface)this.controls[index]).Event += this.Handler;
```

You just have the `IsAssignableFrom` inverted.

---

For your case, however, the **best** way to do this test is the following for performance and clarity improvements:

```
if (this.controls[index] is MyInterface)
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be being dense but can't you just do:

```
MyInterface foo = this.controls[index] as MyInterface;
if (foo != null) { /* do stuff */ }
```

(and of course the real `MyInterface` should have a name starting with `I`)